# Brake pad too low on rotor?

Tags: mountain-bike, disc-brake, brake-pads, rotor, alignment

I just bought a new Clarks CFR-06 rotor to try to improve my crappy Tektro Auriga, but it seems that I made another bad choice. After just a couple of minutes of trials, I noticed that the pads are rubbing "too low" (3 mm) as you can see in the photo. Do I need to put some washer between the caliper and the adapter, or this is just fine?
Thanks[image]

Comment: I cannot see anything unusual on the picture; the braking traces are where I would normally expect them. Given that both inner and outer edges of the disc braking area are wobbly-shaped, it is hard to predict the optimal path for the pad without doing some comparative simulations or experimental runs. Unless there are clearance issues (disc scraping caliper or caliper touching spider), it should be fine. I want to add that I did use an extra pair of thin (~1 mm) washers with the adapter to fine-tune position of a caliper, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

IMO, this is fine. I base that answer on the fact that I've been running Avid BB7s on Shimano Centerlock rotors and they are also too low, and in fact abrade down into the arms a bit. After thousands of (**touring**) miles, this has caused no braking issues nor even any perceptible pinging, etc.

There is more on this [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/72984/which-shimano-centerlock-rotors-work-with-avid-bb7-mountain-brake-calipers).

If you put in a couple spacers, you'll of course have a little less pad grabbing the rotor. Whether or not it's sufficient braking at that point will be up to you to judge.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers.
For the moment i have put a couple of washers. The height of the caliper seems ok now. Still i have to test it.
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Good work.  I'd suggest you look for some wider washers (ie larger diameter) to help support the rotor.  What you've got will have more sideways wobble than if there were no washers.  Ideally, they'd be as large as the mating surfaces.

Comment: So you think it might be dangerous as it is now? (still have to test it)

Comment: no its not dangerous, but it could be stiffer if the washers were wider.  As is should work absolutely fine, but it could flex subtly under braking loads.  Wider washers will decrease that potential flex.   But if you find it works now, then leave it as-is.